# Poetry Issue with uploading Langchain/Langserve app to gcloud Cloud Run

Tags: gcloud, langchain, python-poetry

I am trying to create a small Langchain/Langserve app.
The app uses poetry and works fine on my local machine, however when I upload it to Cloud run using "cloud run deploy", I get the following message:
*"poetry.core.masonry.utils.module.ModuleOrPackageNotFound: No file/folder found for package pdfbot-app"* where pdfbot is my app.

Also, at the end of the trace stack I get: ***Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with pdfbot-app (0.0.1 /code/packages/pdfBot-app) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --use-pep517 --editable "/code/packages/pdfBot-app"'.***

Again my app works fine when running locally. Any idea what could be the issue or what I should check?
Thanks

Trace stack:

```
    ChefBuildError

  Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke build_editable
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 273, in build_editable
      return hook(wheel_directory, config_settings, metadata_directory)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/tmp/tmpsedf5755/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/api.py", line 82, in build_editable
      return WheelBuilder.make_in(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/tmp/tmpsedf5755/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 88, in make_in
      wb.build(target_dir=directory)
    File "/tmp/tmpsedf5755/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 118, in build
      self._add_pth(zip_file)
    File "/tmp/tmpsedf5755/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 147, in _add_pth
      for include in self._module.includes:
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/functools.py", line 1001, in __get__
      val = self.func(instance)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/tmp/tmpsedf5755/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/builder.py", line 97, in _module
      return Module(
             ^^^^^^^
    File "/tmp/tmpsedf5755/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/utils/module.py", line 65, in __init__
      raise ModuleOrPackageNotFound(
  poetry.core.masonry.utils.module.ModuleOrPackageNotFound: No file/folder found for package pdfbot-app
```

For completeness, here is my pyproject.tml file:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "pdfbot-serve"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [
    { include = "app" },
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
uvicorn = "^0.23.2"
langserve = {extras = ["server"], version = ">=0.0.30"}
pydantic = "<2"
pdfBot-app = {path = "packages/pdfBot-app", develop = true}


[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
langchain-cli = ">=0.0.15"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=0.12"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```